# Chained combo boxes with autocomplete, auto complete data should come from db table

Tags: autocomplete, combobox, chained

How to make
Chained comboboxes with autocomplete, without reloading the page
auto complete data should come from db table.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Select2**

Basically, you set up server to accept a query on some URL, and return json. Then you configure Select2 to use that URL.

This is the official page of Select2. It has example code for this.

http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

For chained comboboxes, try something like this:

```
$('country_box_selector').on('change', function(){
  update_states($(this).val())
})

update_states = function (country) {
  // Fetch and replace states based on passed country
}
```

Comment: Thank you...
I have done the same thing by using jquery ui autocomplete combobox.
I am getting data to one combobox but I am facing problems while changing the data of second combobox when i select a option in first combobox.

I need two comboboxes, One is Country and another one is State.
When I select a country in first combobox, in second combobox states of first combobox should come.